# How can I extract value by using Extract Text Processor?

Tags: regex, apache-nifi, flowfile

I need to extract a property by using an extract text processor

I have a `Replace Text` processor that has the property

```
"Input_String": 
    {"columnId":"19","value":"Helloworld","name":"Test"},
"Message_Type":"ADT_A01"
```

I am trying to extract 'Input_String' by using ExtractText processor with the following regular expression:

```
"Input_String"\s*:\s*\{[^}]*\}
```

but it returns:

```
"Input_String":{"columnId":"19","value":"Helloworld","name":"Test"},
```

However, I only need it to return its value

```
{"columnId":"19","value":"Helloworld","name":"Test"}
```

How can I get only the value of the property

Comment: if this is content of flowfile then EvaluateJsonPath could be a better solution because it looks like json

Answer (score 0):

@Chinnu

EvaluateJsonPath is what you need here.  In this processor click + and add property columnID with value $.columnId. Repeat for other values.

If your input string is not the json object {...} and includes any string characters before or after the {}, then use ExtractText to get the entire object as the flowfile.  Then use EvaluateJsonPath as above.